# H ow to compute the integral of an absolute value

Tags: calculus

How do we compute the integral of an absolute value?

> $\int |x|\,dx$
>
> $\int_0^1 |x|\,dx$

Comment: I think you should add `dx` inside the integrals. :)

Comment: Break the integral down into parts where $x>0$ and when $x<0$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\newcommand{\+}{^{\dagger}}%
 \newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle #1 \right\rangle}%
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace #1 \right\rbrace}%
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack #1 \right\rbrack}%
 \newcommand{\dd}{{\rm d}}%
 \newcommand{\isdiv}{\,\left.\right\vert\,}%
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}%
 \newcommand{\equalby}[1]{{#1 \atop {= \atop \vphantom{\huge A}}}}%
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,{\rm e}^{#1}\,}%
 \newcommand{\floor}[1]{\,\left\lfloor #1 \right\rfloor\,}%
 \newcommand{\ic}{{\rm i}}%
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}%
 \newcommand{\ket}[1]{\left\vert #1\right\rangle}%
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left( #1 \right)}%
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\pp}{{\cal P}}%
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,#2\,}\,}%
 \newcommand{\sech}{\,{\rm sech}}%
 \newcommand{\sgn}{\,{\rm sgn}}%
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{{\rm d}^{#1} #2}{{\rm d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\ul}[1]{\underline{#1}}%
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert #1 \right\vert}%
 \newcommand{\yy}{\Longleftrightarrow}$
\begin{align}
\color{#0000ff}{\large\int_{a}^{b}\verts{x}\,\dd x}
&=
\left.\vphantom{\LARGE A}x\verts{x}\,\right\vert_{a}^{b}
-
\int_{a}^{b}x\sgn\pars{x}\,\dd x
=
b\verts{b} - a\verts{a}
-
\left.\vphantom{\LARGE A}{1 \over 2}\,x^{2}\sgn\pars{x}\,\right\vert_{a}^{b}
+
\int_{a}^{b}{1 \over 2}\,x^{2}\bracks{2\delta\pars{x}}\,\dd x
\\[3mm]&=
b\verts{b} - a\verts{a} - {1 \over 2}b\verts{b} + {1 \over 2}a\verts{a}
=
\color{#0000ff}{\large{1 \over 2}\pars{b\verts{b} - a\verts{a}}}
\end{align}

Answer (score 0):

From 0 to 1,|x| is just x. So $\int_0^1|x|dx$ is $\int_0^1xdx$.

And for the indefinite integral,you will have to know whether x is greater than 0 or less than 0.

Comment: what if x<0????

Comment: If x<0, |x|=-x.